# How to fetch the select value if its respective checkbox is checked?

Tags: jquery

```
<tr>
    <td>Product 1</td>
    <td class="data">
        <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="items[]" value="item1">Item 1</li>
            <li>
                <select name="categories[]">
                    <option value="cat1">Category 1</option>
                    <option value="cat2">Category 2</option>
                    <option value="cat3">Category 3</option>
                </select>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="items[]" value="item2">Item 2</li>
            <li>
                <select name="categories[]">
                    <option value="cat1">Category 1</option>
                    <option value="cat2">Category 2</option>
                    <option value="cat3">Category 3</option>
                </select>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </td>

    <td>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="save">
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Product 2</td>
    <td class="data">
        <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="items[]" value="item1">Item 1</li>
            <li>
                <select name="categories[]">
                    <option value="cat1">Category 1</option>
                    <option value="cat2">Category 2</option>
                    <option value="cat3">Category 3</option>
                </select>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="items[]" value="item2">Item 2</li>
            <li>
                <select name="categories[]">
                    <option value="cat1">Category 1</option>
                    <option value="cat2">Category 2</option>
                    <option value="cat3">Category 3</option>
                </select>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </td>

    <td>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="save">
    </td>
</tr>
```

The table is dynamically generated from jquery. Here what I have done till now is when I click one of the save button, I have fetched the value of checked show time from the related . But I also want to fetch the value of categories if its respective checkbox is checked.

Here's is the code that I've till now:

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '.save', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var show_times = new Array();
        $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each (function () {
            show_times.push(this.value);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select element lies in next sibling of input elements parent lki. you can traverse to closest ul and then find select element in it:

```
$(document).on('click', '.save', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var show_times = new Array();
    var show_times_select = new Array();
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function () {
        show_times.push(this.value);
        show_times_select.push($(this).closest('ul').find('select').val());
    });
    console.log(show_times );
    console.log(show_times_select );
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but when I console log it, it says selectvalue is not defined.

Comment: Sorry, but it still says selectvalue is not defined. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Here I've done so far.

`$(document).on('click', '.save', function (e) {`
`e.preventDefault();`
`var show_times = new Array();`
`$(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function () {`
`show_times.push(this.value);`
`var selectvalue = $(this).closest('ul').find('select').val();`
`});`
`console.log(show_times);`
`console.log(selectvalue);`
`});`
`</script>`

Comment: see. you will need to maintain one more array for pushing select element value here. check the updated answer.

Comment: @skonmai: glad it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

The `select` is a sibling. Use this way:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each (function () {
    var selectvalue = $(this).next().val();
    show_times.push(selectvalue);
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but when I console log it, it says selectvalue is not defined.

Comment: @skonmai This happens when there is no `checked` checkboxes.

Comment: I have checked with checked checkboxes, but still it says selectvalue is not defined. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

use Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var arr = [];
    var counter = 0;
    $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){

        if($(this).is(":checked")){

           arr[counter] =  $(" select",$(this).closest("ul")).val();
        counter++;
        }
    });

console.log(arr);
});
```

[Deome](https://jsfiddle.net/farhanbaloch/prrmtpuf/)